# My bot discord doesn't work. I don't know why?

Tags: javascript, discord

it's a code of bot discord ! i have one erreur and i can't fix please help me.
I have found code here https://maah.gitbooks.io/discord-bots/examples/restarting-and-shutting-down.html

```
    client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.type != 'text' || message.author.bot)
    return;

  let command = message.content.split(' ')[0].slice(1);
  let args = message.content.replace('.' + command, '').trim();
  let isBotOwner = message.author.id == '554593664081461248';

  //console.log(command);

  switch (command) {
    case 'restart': {
      if (!isBotOwner)
        return;

      message.channel.send('Restarting...').then(m => {
        client.destroy().then(() => {
          client.login('token');
        });
      });
      break;
    }


    case 'shutdown': {
      if (!isBotOwner)
        return;

      message.channel.send('Shutting down...').then(m => {
        client.destroy();
      });
      break;
    }
  }
);
```

error is

> /volume1/web/anju.my-bot.fun/index.js:99
>   });

Thank you

Comment: The code is missing one closing brace, so it's syntactically invalid. Check that every block ends where you want it to end.

Comment: I don't know your intentions. It looks like the brace is missing just before the last closing parenthesis, but I can't be sure if this will give the logic you need.

Comment: @ArthurGorbana just add 1 } before the ) at the end

Comment: Check this - https://pastebin.com/nRdVtVbs - maybe it will work. Again, if it doesn't work, you have to check your code yourself, we don't know what you want it to do.

Comment: THX problem is solved